# so + why + verb?? (Grammar)

Tags: grammar, questions

I've just seen the sentence below in my grammar book:

> You still have a lot of paint, so why not paint the bedroom too?

and I thought it should have been:

> "You still have a lot of paint, so why **don't** you paint the bedroom too?"

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your sentence is not wrong, but neither is the sentence from your grammar book.

Answer (score 2):

We use 'why not' followed by the base (infinitive) form of a verb (without 'to') to make a suggestion: [You have paint left] why not paint the bedroom? [your car is being repaired] why not borrow Jim's car? [You are bored] why not read a book?

We use 'why' followed by the base form of a verb to suggest that an action is unnecessary or pointless: Why walk when you can ride in a bus? Why eat hamburger when you can have steak? Why complain when nothing will be done?

[Why and why not](https://www.englishgrammar.org/why-and-why-not/)

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine and mean the same thing.  Example:

> **Why not** go see a movie tonight?
>
> **Why don't we** go see a movie tonight?

Note with "why not" you don't have to specify the subject.  I might suggest, "Why not paint the bedroom?" because I don't want to help you, but I want to avoid explicitly saying that *you* will be the one doing the work.

> A: Since you're already cleaning the kitchen, why not make dinner?
>   B: You mean, **we** will make dinner together?
>   A: No, I mean **you** should make **us** dinner.  I'm going to take a nap.  Wake me when it's ready?